# How to write let two Python abstract classes implement each other's abstract methods?

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order, linearization

Suppose you have abstract classes `A1` and `A2`. Each of them has an abstract method and a concrete method.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A0(ABC):
    pass

class A1(A0, ABC):
    def foo(self):
        return 1

    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class A2(A0, ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
    
    def bar(self):
        return 10
```

Now you want to mix-in them togather to implement each other's abstract method:

```py
class C(A2, A1, A0):
    def all(self):
        return (super().foo(), super().bar())


C().all()
```

However the above code does not work because I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class C with abstract method foo
```

How can I create `C` so that it can mix-in both `A1` and `A2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution similar to [Gábor Fekete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464041/g%c3%a1bor-fekete), except that the abstract methods are extracted to new `ABC`'s, to avoid changing `A0`.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A0(ABC):
    pass

class AbstractFoo(A0, ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class AbstractBar(A0, ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class A1(AbstractFoo, AbstractBar, A0, ABC):
    def foo(self):
        return 1

class A2(AbstractFoo, AbstractBar, A0, ABC):
    def bar(self):
        return 10

class C(A2, A1, A0):
    def all(self):
        return (super().foo(), super().bar())

C().all()
```

Answer (score 1):

I moved the abstract methods to A0, and only implemented one of each in the A1, A2 classes, then C has both of them implemented:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A0(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class A1(A0, ABC):
    def foo(self):
        return 1

class A2(A0, ABC):
    def bar(self):
        return 10

class C(A1,A2):
    def all(self):
        return (super().foo(), super().bar())


print(C().all())
# can't instantiate A0,A1,A2, as these have not implemented abstract methods
# print(A1()) # won't work
# print(A2()) # won't work
```

Comment: Moving abstract methods to `A0` would change `A0`'s functionality. I would move them to new `ABC`'s instead.